# NDVI values of Landsat 7 and 8 differ for same location and year (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8, landsat-7

The NDVI values for the same location and same year differ between Landsat 7 and 8. Even though I would expect a small difference the difference I found is too high.

[image: screenshot of graph output and code]

```
 var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_ANNUAL_NDVI')   
  .filterBounds(UStest)
  .filterDate('2000-01-01' , '2020-01-01')
  .select('NDVI')

var series1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    collection1, UStest, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 30, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Landsat7 annual NDVI',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,});


var collection2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_ANNUAL_NDVI')   
  .filterBounds(UStest)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01' , '2020-01-01')
  .select('NDVI')

var series2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    collection2, UStest, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 30, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Landsat8 annual NDVI',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,});

Map.addLayer(UStest, {color: 'FF0000'});
print(series1,series2);
var palette = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(collection1,palette);
```

Comment: Honestly I think you would be better off calculating yearly NDVI yourself, I suspect there's a reason those datasets are completely unlisted in the GEE catalog, add one to the map and you'll see they're full of defects. Also, consider that Landsat 7 data is severely flawed after 2003 due to a mirror failure.

Comment: Another option is to use MODIS NDVI and calculate the yearly mean, if you want to skip the cloud processing and masking.